# perform df.loc to groupby df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I've a `df` consisted of person, origin and destination

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'PersonID':['1','1','2','2','2','3'],'O':['A','B','C','B','A','X'],'D':['B','A','B','A','B','Y']})
```

the df:

```
PersonID    O       D
   1        A       B
   1        B       A      
   2        C       B
   2        B       A
   2        A       B
   3        X       Y
```

I have grouped by the df with `df_grouped = df.groupby(['O','D'])` and match them with another dataframe, `taxi`.

```
TaxiID    O       D
  T1      B       A
  T2      A       B
  T3      C       B
```

similarly, I group by the `taxi` with their `O` and `D`. Then I merged them after aggregating and counting the PersonID and TaxiID per O-D pair. I did it to see how many taxis are available for how many people.

```
O     D     PersonID    TaxiID
             count      count
A     B        2          1
B     A        2          1
C     B        1          1
```

Now, I want to perform `df.loc` to take **only** those PersonID that was counted in the merged file. How can I do this? I've tried to us:

```
seek = df.loc[df.PersonID.isin(merged['PersonID'])]
```

but it returns an empty dataframe. What can I do to do this?

edit: I attach the complete code for this case using dummy data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'PersonID':['1','1','2','2','2','3'],'O':['A','B','C','B','A','X'],'D':['B','A','B','A','B','Y']})
taxi = pd.DataFrame({'TaxiID':['T1','T2','T3'],'O':['B','A','C'],'D':['A','B','B']})

df_grouped = df.groupby(['O','D'])
taxi_grouped = taxi.groupby(['O','D'])

dfm = df_grouped.agg({'PersonID':['count',list]}).reset_index()
tgm = taxi_grouped.agg({'TaxiID':['count',list]}).reset_index()

merged = pd.merge(dfm, tgm, how='inner')

seek = df.loc[df.PersonID.isin(merged['PersonID'])]
```

Comment: Can you show your complete code?

Comment: @jezrael I've edited it and add the complete code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select `MultiIndex` by `tuple` with [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) for scalars from nested lists:

```
seek = df.loc[df.PersonID.isin(merged[('PersonID', 'list')].explode().unique())]
print (seek)
  PersonID  O  D
0        1  A  B
1        1  B  A
2        2  C  B
3        2  B  A
4        2  A  B
```

For better performance is possible use `set comprehension` with flatten:

```
seek = df.loc[df.PersonID.isin(set(z for x in merged[('PersonID', 'list')] for z in x))]
print (seek)
  PersonID  O  D
0        1  A  B
1        1  B  A
2        2  C  B
3        2  B  A
4        2  A  B
```

Comment: I expect it should be faster to use `merged[('PersonID', 'list')].explode().unique()` for large dataframes.

Comment: @mozway - ya, agree.

Comment: @mozway @jezrael these works perfectly, thanks! so basically what it did was converting the `merged['PersonID']` into a list, then the `df.loc` is taking the data from df with that list as the reference. Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: @Ricky You are close, it is numpy array like list for first solution, for second it is set used for reference.